# Why does fontspec change the maths accents (and only with lualatex)?

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, luatex, accents

In the minimal example that follows luatex doesn't place the accent correctly (it's too far left):

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\(\bar E\)
\end{document}
```

But if I compile it with xelatex, or with lualatex and `\setromanfont{Linux Libertine O}` commented out, everything works fine.

I believed that fonspec was only for text, and not for math. So why this strange behaviour ?

Comment: Try loading `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov : It works. Maybe you could make an answer of you comment.

Comment: Actually, I can't see any difference at all with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. I use TeX Live 2011. Perhaps you could tell your distribution and show an image of what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I see the same with TeXlive 2011 (on W7), the bar is shifted left.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I have TeXLive 2011 (on MacOs 10.7), fully updated. And the result really depend on the choice of the police (with Palatino, for example, it works fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I get when calling `\showlists` after the formula:

### LuaTeX

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 6
\whatsit
.\localinterlinepenalty=0
.\localbrokenpenalty=0
.\localleftbox=null
.\localrightbox=null
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0, direction TLT
\mathon
\vbox(8.20554+0.0)x7.95831, direction TLT
.\hbox(5.67776+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^V
.\kern-4.30554
.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.95831, direction TLT
..\OML/cmm/m/it/10 E
\mathoff
```

### XeTeX

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 6
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\mathon
\vbox(8.20554+0.0)x7.95831
.\hbox(5.67776+0.0)x0.0, shifted 2.31252
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^V
.\kern-4.30554
.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.95831
..\OML/cmm/m/it/10 E
\mathoff
```

There is clearly a problem with LuaTeX; it can be due to `fontspec` as, when not loading it or loading a different font than Linux Libertine O (I tested Old Standard and TeX Gyre Termes) I get the following:

### LuaTeX (without Linux Libertine O)

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 6
\whatsit
.\localinterlinepenalty=0
.\localbrokenpenalty=0
.\localleftbox=null
.\localrightbox=null
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0, direction TLT
\mathon
\vbox(8.20554+0.0)x7.95831, direction TLT
.\hbox(5.67776+0.0)x0.0, shifted 2.31252, direction TLT
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^V
.\kern-4.30554
.\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.95831, direction TLT
..\OML/cmm/m/it/10 E
\mathoff
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two LuaTeX outputs....

Comment: @JPi I see no `shifted` in the first case.

Comment: @JPi On the other hand, the problem seems to have been solved already with TeX Live 2012 (issued some months after my answer).

Comment: Yes, I was just reading this because it showed up when you answered my question posted 20 Jan 17.